# How to select at least 3 consecutive identical values in 3D array by the given axis in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, raster, python-xarray

I have 3D array (axis[0]=time, axis[1]=rlat, axis[2]=rlon) with the vales [1] and [0]. I need to find the occurence of at least 3 or more consecutive values [1] by the axis [0] (3 or more consecutive occurence should be counted as 1 event). The result should be 2D array which sum these occurences (events).

This is the data array

```
xarray.DataArray'tasmax'time: 155, rlat: 6, rlon: 4
array([[[0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0]], ...
```

I try this, but I do not know how to specify the the three consecutive values by the axis [0]:

```
x1=df[:,:,:]
x2=df[:-1,:,:]
x3=df[:-2,:,:]

x[np.where((x1==1)&(x2==1)&(x3==1))] = 1.0

c=np.sum(x,axis=0)
```

The result should be something like this (but the values should be lower)

```
xarray.DataArray'tasmax'rlat: 6, rlon: 4
array([[24, 20, 14, 11],
       [26, 21, 15, 11],
       [23, 23, 15, 12],
       [14, 15, 14, 11],
       [12, 12, 14, 11],
       [14, 12, 15, 13]])
```

Do you have any ideas, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was only to give a solution for it using two for loops to iteration on the axes 1 and 2.

```
a = np.zeros(shape=(155, 6, 4), dtype=int)

# Test some ones
a[[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 20, 22, 33, 34], 0, 0] = 1
a[[99, 100, 101, 102, 104, 110, 111, 112], -1, -1] = 1

_res = np.zeros(shape=(a.shape[1], a.shape[2]), dtype=int)
for i in range(_res.shape[0]):
    for j in range(_res.shape[1]):
        _sub = a[:, i, j]
        # Get zeros as the edges between consecutive ones
        _zeros_mask = _sub == 0
        _zeros_mask = np.insert(_zeros_mask, obj=0, values=True)
        _zeros_mask = np.append(_zeros_mask, values=True)
        # Get the positions of the zeros edges
        _inx = np.arange(_zeros_mask.shape[0])
        _inx = _inx[_zeros_mask]
        # Compute the distance between successive zeros as it is the numbers of ones between
        _diff = np.diff(_inx)
        _res[i, j] = np.sum(_diff > 3)
print(_res.shape, _res)
```